# iOS Nested UITableView Loading All Cells Unnecessarily

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In 2 of my view controllers I have table views in which one or more of the cells contain a nested `UITableView`, which contains a further 20-30 cells.

The top level table loads cells as necessary, when the cells come into view, but the nested table seems to request all the cells at once even if only the top cell is visible. How can this be prevented?

Comment: Do you need to have a nested tableview in your cell? You could use multiple sections, so instead of 1 section having 10 cells, you have 10 sections each with 1 cell, and then when you need to display the child cells, you just add them to the relevant section? This should solve your problem.

Comment: Agree with @totiG, you really want to avoid nesting `UITableView`s.

Comment: @totiG Unfortunately yes, one of the cells requires two table views side by side and the other includes an ImageView beside the table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dynamic sized cells?

If so, you need to specify proper height of the cells either by `UITableView.estimatedRowHeight` or `UITableViewDelegate.estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I usually cache the height of the cell on `UITableViewDelegate.willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and use the cached height at `UITableViewDelegate.estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

That solved the similar problem I had.

Otherwise, all the cells are loaded in the beginning even though they are not on screen.